# How can I run multiple SQL queries in parallel in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, multiprocessing, psycopg2

In **AWS Lambda** function (*Python 3.8 runtime*), I created two processes. In each of these processes, I'm trying to run two completely different functions in parallel, each running an SQL query. Each of these SQL queries interacts with different **PostgreSQL** database (*psycopg2 driver*) tables.

As you can see from my code, I create a single [connection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/connection.html#connection) object at the very beginning AWS Lambda function. In each of the running processes, I use this connection object. Each process uses its own cursor. At the end of each process, the cursor closes.

Also, I use the global `connection.autocommit = True` option.

The `MemorySize` of the AWS Lambda function is `10240`.

When I tried to execute my code I got an error with the following content in both processes:

```
[ERROR] psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```

According the [psycopg2 documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#thread-and-process-safety):

> when using a module such as multiprocessing or a forking web deploy
> method such as FastCGI make sure to create the connections after the
> fork.

Creating an object with a database connection in each process can slow down the AWS Lambda function very much. Isn't it? As you can see, I use a global variable (`POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION`) to re-use a previously created database connection.

What should I do in this situation? I need to run multiple SQL queries in parallel in AWS Lambda.

**Code snippet:**

```
import logging
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
from psycopg2.extras import RealDictCursor
from functools import wraps
from typing import *
import databases  # AWS Lambda Layer

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# The connection to the database will be created the first time the AWS Lambda function is called.
# Any subsequent call to the function will use the same database connection until the container stops.
POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION = None

# Initialize global variables with parameters for settings.
POSTGRESQL_USERNAME = os.environ["POSTGRESQL_USERNAME"]
POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD = os.environ["POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD"]
POSTGRESQL_HOST = os.environ["POSTGRESQL_HOST"]
POSTGRESQL_PORT = os.environ["POSTGRESQL_PORT"]
POSTGRESQL_DB_NAME = os.environ["POSTGRESQL_DB_NAME"]


def reuse_or_recreate_postgresql_connection():
    global POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION
    if not POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION:
        try:
            POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION = databases.create_postgresql_connection(
                POSTGRESQL_USERNAME,
                POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD,
                POSTGRESQL_HOST,
                POSTGRESQL_PORT,
                POSTGRESQL_DB_NAME
            )
        except Exception as error:
            logger.error(error)
            raise Exception("Unable to connect to the PostgreSQL database.")
    return POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION


def execute_parallel_processes(functions: List[Dict[AnyStr, Union[Callable, Dict[AnyStr, Any]]]]) -> Dict[AnyStr, Any]:
    # Create an empty list to keep all parallel processes.
    processes = []

    # Create an empty list of pipes to keep all connections.
    pipes = []

    # Create a process per function.
    for index, function in enumerate(functions):
        # Check whether the input arguments have keys in their dictionaries.
        try:
            target = function["function_object"]
        except KeyError as error:
            logger.error(error)
            raise Exception(error)
        try:
            kwargs = function["function_arguments"]
        except KeyError as error:
            logger.error(error)
            raise Exception(error)

        # Create a pipe for communication.
        parent_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        pipes.append(parent_pipe)
        kwargs["pipe"] = child_pipe

        # Create a process.
        process = Process(target=target, kwargs=kwargs)
        processes.append(process)

    # Start all parallel processes.
    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    # Wait until all parallel processes are finished.
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    # Get the results of all processes.
    results = {}
    for pipe in pipes:
        results = {**results, **pipe.recv()}

    # Return the results of all processes.
    return results


def psycopg2_cursor(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(**kwargs):
        try:
            postgresql_connection = kwargs["postgresql_connection"]
        except KeyError as error:
            logger.error(error)
            raise Exception(error)
        cursor = postgresql_connection.cursor(cursor_factory=RealDictCursor)
        result = function(cursor=cursor, **kwargs)
        cursor.close()
        return result
    return wrapper

@psycopg2_cursor
def get_product_data(**kwargs) -> None:
    # Check whether the input arguments have keys in their dictionaries.
    try:
        cursor = kwargs["cursor"]
    except KeyError as error:
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)
    try:
        arguments = kwargs["sql_arguments"]
    except KeyError as error:
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)
    try:
        pipe = kwargs["pipe"]
    except KeyError as error:
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)

    # Prepare the SQL query.
    statement = "select * from products where product_id = %(product_id)s limit 1;"

    # Execute the SQL query dynamically, in a convenient and safe way.
    try:
        cursor.execute(statement, arguments)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)

    # Send data to the pipe and then close it.
    pipe.send({
        "product_data": cursor.fetchone()
    })
    pipe.close()

@psycopg2_cursor
def get_user_data(**kwargs) -> None:
    # Check whether the input arguments have keys in their dictionaries.
    try:
        cursor = kwargs["cursor"]
    except KeyError as error:
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)
    try:
        arguments = kwargs["sql_arguments"]
    except KeyError as error:
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)
    try:
        pipe = kwargs["pipe"]
    except KeyError as error:
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)

    # Prepare the SQL query.
    statement = "select * from users where user_id = %(user_id)s limit 1;"

    # Execute the SQL query dynamically, in a convenient and safe way.
    try:
        cursor.execute(statement, arguments)
    except Exception as error:
        logger.error(error)
        raise Exception(error)

    # Send data to the pipe and then close it.
    pipe.send({
        "user_data": cursor.fetchone()
    })
    pipe.close()


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    postgresql_connection = reuse_or_recreate_postgresql_connection()

    # Run several functions in parallel to get all necessary data from different databases tables.
    results_of_processes = execute_parallel_processes([
        {
            "function_object": get_product_data,
            "function_arguments": {
                "postgresql_connection": postgresql_connection,
                "sql_arguments": {
                    "product_id": event["product_id"]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "function_object": get_user_data,
            "function_arguments": {
                "postgresql_connection": postgresql_connection,
                "sql_arguments": {
                    "user_id": event["user_id"]
                }
            }
        }
    ])

    product_data = results_of_processes["product_data"]
    user_data = results_of_processes["user_data"]

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(results_of_processes)
    }
```

The **AWS Lambda Layer** called `databases`:

```
def create_postgresql_connection(db_username, db_password, db_host, db_port, db_name):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user=db_username, password=db_password, host=db_host, port=db_port, database=db_name)
    connection.autocommit = True
    return connection
```

Comment: Based on the error I'd say you have a problem with your connection, specifically a SSL problem: `SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac`. Check that your `POSTGRESQL_HOST` and `POSTGRESQL_PORT` etc. are set properly. This has nothing to do with the "performance" of your code. This should easily fit in a 256MB memory Lambda, probably 128.

Comment: @Jens Thank you for your response. I checked the values of `POSTGRESQL_HOST`, `POSTGRESQL_PORT`  constant variables. Then are available and correct. As you can see from my code, I have the `reuse_or_recreate_postgresql_connection` function. Inside that function, I can create a connection object if it is necessary. I moved the connection function itself to `AWS Lambda Layers` (`create_postgresql_connection` function) because I often use it in other AWS Lambda functions. Can you check my post again, please?! The `create_postgresql_connection` function is pretty simple. So I am confused.

Comment: Check this blog post. Same issue with _a_ solution: https://medium.com/@philamersune/fixing-ssl-error-decryption-failed-or-bad-record-mac-d668e71a5409. I'd highly recommend you start writing sync code and check if it is fast enough for your use case. It seems like a premature optimisation that is unnecessary at this point in time. Your queries look very simple and fast. So just do them one after another. This will make your code much, much, much simpler. In the end you just fetch a single user and a single product.

Comment: I've already come across this post. I'm not sure that it will work in the context of AWS Lambda. Since the following describes solutions for Django. Don't you think so? In any case, thank you! I came to multiprocessing because my current synchronous code started not to meet the performance speed.

Comment: In the end they created a new connection per thread. Maybe start with this then and check if it is fast enough. So don't share the connection globally, but create it every time. That was ultimately the solution used in the blog post.

Comment: As a result, we returned to what I said at the very beginning of my post. In theory, creating an object with a database connection in each process can slow down the AWS Lambda function very much. Isn't it? So I was looking for other ways to parallelize the execution of functions and SQL queries. If you have any other ideas, let me know please.

Comment: It is true, that it is a best practice to just create a single database connection when the Lambda function is initialised. But still, try creating a new client for every request and _measure_ if it is really too slow. Otherwise, you are just claiming it is too slow, without _knowing_ it is too slow. Have a look at AWS X-Ray which can help you a lot to find out if your code is too slow. In my experience with Go and Java creating a database connection is quite cheap. I doubt it is that much different in Python.